# Como Desordenar, Mezclar, Barajar un Array en Java

Tags: java, array, funciones, algoritmos

En otros lenguajes existen funciones para mezclar de forma aleatoria los elementos de un *array* (como la función [shuffle](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.shuffle.php) de PHP), en el caso de Java desconozco si existe alguna función semejante, por lo que de momento veo que se emplean funciones creadas a partir de código para dicho propósito.

En muchas paginas ([como el sitio oficial en ingles](http://Random%20shuffling%20of%20an%20array)) se brindan códigos de funciones que pueden resolver el problema, pero algunas de las soluciones encontradas parecen estar algo desactualizadas.

Incluso muchas veces las respuestas que circulan por *internet* no son del todo eficaces y no funcionan el 100% de los casos.

Lo que se busca es que el algoritmo pueda:

- Desordenar *arrays* que contengan cualquier tipo de elementos
  (caracteres, números, cadenas, arrays, etc.).
- Que pueda desordenar arrays de cualquier tamaño.
- y que el resultado tenga un grado de entropia (desorden) aceptable.

Aquí un ejemplo de código en java

```
private static void shuffleArray(int[] array)
{
    int index;
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        index = random.nextInt(i + 1);
        if (index != i)
        {
            array[index] ^= array[i];
            array[i] ^= array[index];
            array[index] ^= array[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Código obtenido de [Random shuffling of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18456998/4832311)

¿Como puedo desordenar cualquier tipo de *array* sin importar el tamaño y el tipo de elementos que contiene con un código mas corto con menos lineas?

Gracias.

Comment: Buenas the-breaker. El problema que yo le veo a la pregunta no es tanto que esté duplicada  si no que no veo un problema concreto. Como ya sabrás, aqui ayudamos con dudas concretas y tu pregunta *"Existe alguna otra forma mas simple"*  parece estar basado en opiniones y generaría discrepancias. Por favor, reformula tu publicación para aclarar tu situación concreta. Un saludo!

Comment: Y ahora la respuesta es, no uses un int[] array, usa un generic, porque a la funcion que desordena no le importa el tipo de dato. podrias usar un object y seria lo mismo..

Comment: @gbianchi entiendo pero esa respuesta es del 2013, me interesa saber si al 2019 ya existen otros métodos mas actuales.

Comment: De que respuestas hablas? las que te marcamos como duplicadas son de hace 2 años...

Comment: @gbianchi disculpa me refería a la respuesta de la que obtuve el código (del sitio en ingles).

Comment: Para la posteridad, sí que existe una forma de hacer shuffle en java, ha de hacerse con una colección y List es la colección más cercana a un array, por lo que: `Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(array)).toArray(new int[0]);` debería funcionar.

Comment: @gbianchi en vista de que la pregunta ya no esta relacionada con la otra pregunta duplicada y luego de las modificaciones realzadas ¿existe algún motivo por la que deba permanecer cerrada?

Comment: @the-breaker yo la reabro, para que decida el resto. Pero para mi sigue siendo duplicada. Y lo que es pero, lo que dice david no es real. El metodo shuffle hace exactamente lo mismo que lo que escribiste. Miren el codigo fuente o [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2249526/73749)

Comment: @DavidDPG El metodo shuffle hace exactamente lo mismo que el codigo descripto arriba. Mira mi comentario anterior.

Comment: @gbianchi No he dicho lo contrario en ningún momento, sólo aclaraba que existe y se puede aplicar a arrays con un poco de adaptación. Igualmente me parece que una solución de una línea que te permite no repetir código es mejor que implementar uno mismo un algoritmo en el que podrían aparecer bugs.

Comment: gracias @gbianchi, no soy experto en java así que creo que en las respuestas podre entender mejor de lo que hablan en comentarios y al igual que con los metodos de ordenación no creo que exista un único camino, saludos.

Comment: Lo que pasa @DavidDPG que ese codigo no es mas corto ni tiene menos lineas.. es mas.. tiene mas lineas.. Yo sigo sin entender el sentido de esta pregunta. Pero me abro. Sigo sin entender que tipo de respuestas se estan buscando.

Comment: @the-breaker ninguna de las respuesta que te dieron difieren de las respuestas que tenias en la pregunta anterior. Sigo sin entender el sentido de esta pregunta y menos el de dar una recompensa. Nadie te dio un algoritmo "mas corto" ni "mejor", solo explicaron el que ya tenias y que ya estaba explicado. Ahora se entiende porque te dije que esta pregunta era un duplicado?

Comment: @gbianchi tómelo con calma, aun no termina el plazo, acabo de buscar la otra pregunta, entre las respuestas están una con explicación sin código, otra en javascript y otra con código sin mucha explicación, ninguna de esas respuestas me es satisfactoria, lo siento.

Comment: @gbianchi en el primer párrafo deja claro que busca una función como la shuffle de PHP pero en Java, pero que no encuentra ninguna y sólo encuentra funciones de otros usuarios para dicho propósito. Por tanto la respuesta es la que indica David DPG. Existe un Shuffle para los objetos Collection, por tanto la solución más sencilla y que responde a la pregunta es la que ha planteado.

Comment: Podrías usar un mergesort modificado por tal de que mezclara todo tipo de listas pero, ¿vale la pena teniendo ya el método shuffle?

Comment: @Yeste si el método que sugieres es mas largo e implica mas cambios no valdría la pena.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Previa conversión de tu array a un `List`

```
Arrays.asList(Object)
```

Tienes el método [shuffle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)) de la clase `Collections` que permite permutar aleatoriamente una lista especificada utilizando una fuente predeterminada aleatoria.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class PruebaShuffle {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     List<String> values = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D");
     Collections.shuffle(values);
     System.out.println(values);
   }
}
```

Puedes ver algunos ejemplos más de su uso en [java-shuffle-collection](https://www.baeldung.com/java-shuffle-collection)

Comment: Aparte de que estás respondiendo a una pregunta que tiene un contenido muy amplio (*ponedme algoritmos de mezcla de listas*), tu respuesta se parece sospechosamente a mi comentario...

Comment: gracias por la respuesta y @DavidDPG entiendo que la pregunta pueda ser un poco amplia, para compensar eso ofrezco la recompensa, ademas como indique también es importante la explicación del método.

Comment: Voy a marcar la respuesta como aceptada ya que es la que resuelve el problema, pero creo que esta algo incompleta, por ejemplo hace falta mencionar que para que funcione se debe importar el paquete `java.util`. Dejo esta **[demostración](https://www.jdoodle.com/a/1D8X)** del código para los que necesiten.

Comment: Ajuste la respuesta para incluir las importaciones. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 6):

Para empezar, ataquemos el problema de un algoritmo de *barajar*. Un algoritmo que puedes usar y funciona "in-place" y tiene complejidad O(N) es el algoritmo de Knut [que puedes consultar aquí](https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Knuth_shuffle). Este es el paso a paso del algoritmo:

1. Para cada sitio `i` desde `0` hasta `N`:

   - Seleccione un número aleatorio `j` entre `0` y `N`
   - Intercambie los valores en los sitios `i` y `j`
2. Listo :)

Luego, en cuanto a tu pregunta de como poder *barajar* cualquier tipo de dato, debes familiarizarte con el tema de [generics en Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html).

Una implementación que puedes usar que cumple con los dos requerimientos va como sigue:

```java
package shuffle;

import java.util.Random;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] numbers = { 1, 3, 4, 5 };
        shuffle(numbers);
        for (int number: numbers) {
            System.out.println(number);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Swap two items of an array.
     * ...
     */
    protected static <T> void swap(T[] array, int i, int j) {
        T temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }

    /**
     * Shuffle an arbitrary array with Knut's algorithm.
     * ...
     */
    public static <T> void shuffle(T[] array) {
        Random random = new Random();
        int i = 0;
        for (int j : random.ints(array.length, 0, array.length).toArray()) {
            swap(array, i++, j);
        }
    }

}
```

La función `swap` intercambia los números en el arreglo, mientras que la función `shuffle` recorre los elementos y genera los números aleatorios.

Los parámetros `<T>` permiten que estas funciones soporten cualquier tipo de objeto, para usarlos agregas `<T>` antes del tipo de retorno y luego usas el tipo `T` en argumentos o en el cuerpo de la función. Sin embargo hay que notar que los genéricos no funcionan con tipos primitivos como `int` o `char`, entonces los arreglos deben ser de tipos como `Integer`, `String`, etc.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta y la explicación.

Comment: Paso la recompensa a esta respuesta por la explicación del método.

Comment: Gracias @the-breaker

Answer (score 0):

https://www.programcreek.com/2012/02/java-method-to-shuffle-an-int-array-with-random-order/ puedes encontar informacion mas detallada.

```
public static int[] RandomizeArray(int a, int b){
            Random rgen = new Random();  // Random number generator     
            int size = b-a+1;
            int[] array = new int[size];

            for(int i=0; i< size; i++){
                array[i] = a+i;
            }

            for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
                int randomPosition = rgen.nextInt(array.length);
                int temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[randomPosition];
                array[randomPosition] = temp;
            }

            for(int s: array)
                System.out.println(s);

            return array;
        }
```

Comment: Yo te recomendaría leer [answer], pues si bien el código puede responder la duda, el solo poner un enlace se considera de baja calidad, toda vez que si la página asociada deja de estar disponible entonces la teoría se pierde

Comment: Aprediz muchas gracias por tu aporte voy a tenerlo en cuenta para mis próximas respuestas

Comment: Yo considero que pudieras editar esta misma, no dejes para mañana lo que puedes hacer hoy 

Comment: lo siento, no puedo darte crédito por código que obtuviste de una pagina sin entenderlo y sin dar una explicación de como funciona.

Comment: Y sin respetar las convenciones de Java...

Answer (score 0):

> Solución parecida a la implementacion de shuffle

```
 //Este codigo es para mostrar los resultados la estrella es el metodo barajar
 public static <E> void main(String args[] ) {

    Integer[] px = new Integer[10];
    for(int i=0; i<px.length;i++) {
        px[i]=i;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<px.length;i++) 
        System.out.print(px[i].toString()+" ");

    System.out.println();

    E[] nuevo = (E[])barajar(px);
    for(int i=0; i<px.length;i++) 
        System.out.print(nuevo[i].toString()+" ");
    }



    //pasa los datos del arreglo a otro arreglo nuevo:
    private static <E> E[] barajar(E[] arreglo) {
    Random random = new Random();
    E[] nuevo= (E[])new Object[arreglo.length];
    ArrayList<Integer> numeros = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    //genera una lista de enteros del 0 hasta el tamaño del arreglo -1
    for(int i=0;i<arreglo.length;i++) {
        numeros.add(i);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<arreglo.length;i++) {
      //de un intervalo  0 a tamaño del arreglo - i tira un numero al azar 
      int indice =  random.nextInt(arreglo.length-i);
      // por cada vuelta que da se reduce el intervalo en uno.
      nuevo[numeros.remove(indice)]=arreglo[i];
    }
    return nuevo;
  }
```

Comment: Esto mas que solucion creativa es una copia exacta de lo que hace el metodo shuffle por dentro :/

Comment: Tenes algún link donde este la implementacion de shuffle para verlo?, originalmente había pensado en un método que agarraga a un arreglo, lo cortaba por la mitad mezclaba las dos mitades intercalando de a 1 o dos según azar , como si fueran un mazo de cartas para mezclar. Pero este me pareció mejor.

Comment: https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/Collections.java

Comment: gbianchi: buenisimo el repositorio gracias, y tenes razón es parecido, no es identico pero se parece.

Answer (score -1):

Por ejemplo tengo una app echa en Java que lo que hace es al arrancar me muestra aleatoria mente una imagen de fondo y lo hago de esta manera.

```
 List<Drawable> Fondos = new ArrayList<>();

 Fondos.add(activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.login1));
 Fondos.add(activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.login2));
 Fondos.add(activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.login3));
 Fondos.add(activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.login4));
 Fondos.add(activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.login5));
 Fondos.add(activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.login6));

 content.setImageDrawable(Fondos.get(new Random().nextInt(Fondos.size())));
```

De esta manera siempre que habro la App me carga una imagen distinta.

Comment: La pregunta se basa en `mezclar de forma aleatoria los elementos de un arreglo`. Tu respuesta se basa en `seleccionar un elemento aleatorio de un arreglo`. Son dos cosas distintas.

Comment: disculpa, me temo que @DamiánAlva tiene razón.